# QGIS Atlas zoom to intersection between two different layers

Tags: qgis, layers, intersection, zoom, atlas

I have two polygon layers, one is about different land owners boundaries and is used for atlas generation, and the other is about forests inside each property. In atlas generation sometimes i want to zoom to the intersection area between the boundary layer (used for atlas iteration) with the forest layer. That is because some times a huge property can have a small part of forest so i want atlas to zoom in to that part of the property. I was thinking to type a function in the scale bar, maybe `$atlasgeometry`, geometry, intersection, etc. Can anyone help with this issue?

I am using QGIS 2.8.1 Wien.

Comment: Would it be an option to always zoom to the intersection?

Comment: Yes, it would be an option.

Comment: Would it be an option to compute an intersection layer to use as the atlas coverage layer?

Comment: Yes, is an option, however I believe that choice will be a "plan b" because i want to avoid create more data. In the near future there will be more map books created in the same way but with different thematic layers in other places and in different times (temporal analysis) so will be tedious to create a new atlas layer every time a map book is needed. Those maps are operative at field, for production, so new actualized maps will be needed constantly.