# How to create an atlas coverage layer from multiple lyers with multiple geometries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, atlas

I have multiple layers (multi-point, multipart polygon, multipart lines). I want to create a hidden coverage layer based on all those to create an atlas of my QGIS project.

Obviously, I can't easily combine different geometries in one layer.

I ended up with the following workflow:

1. convert polygons to lines
2. convert lines to points
3. convert multi-points to single points
4. merge all single-point layers
5. create multipoint layer based on shared attribute (i.e., object
   number)
6. use as hidden coverage layer

Since I will have to do that again in the near future, and this was a hell lot of manual work (and many layers): how would you do that properly?

*Disclaimer: I [read](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220627/how-to-generate-a-map-showing-more-than-one-feature-from-the-coverage-layer-of-a) [several](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78837/how-to-use-qgis-atlas-with-multiple-layers-files-per-coverage) Q/As which are [somewhat](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234267/merging-multiple-vector-layers-to-one-layer-with-multiple-geom-types-with-qgis) [related](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184369/qgis-atlas-zoom-to-intersection-between-two-different-layers), but nothing fits, really. Most seem to deal with displaying multiple layers, not combining multiple layers in one coverage layer. Also, not being able to paste multi-part geometries in a single-part layer seems to be a currently [persistent bug specific to Windows](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16870#note-8).*

Comment: Have you tried automating that workflow with the Graphical Modeller in the Processing toolbox? Might take some of the pain out of it.

Comment: I haven't, but this sure is something I'll try when I have to perform this task next time. But I wonder if this there isn't already a tool which merges shapefile to the lowes common denominator?